# Add Class to Table Row from jQuery Array

Tags: jquery, html

I'm new to jQuery, but I think I'm close here.  I have to display data from SQL View with a couple of Left Outer Joins.  So, I want to set the class of the first table row with a particular PK_DemographicsID as .master and the rest of the rows with the same PK_DemographicsID as .detail.  Obviously, I'm trying to hide the extra rows for each PK_DemographicsID under the first row.

I'm stuck at the if-else where I'm trying to set the class.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thank you.

```
{ ...............
<tbody id="SearchTableBody">
  @foreach (var item in Model.DemographicsAllList)
  {
    <tr data-id={"pkid":"@item.PK_DemographicsID"}>.....</tr>
  }
</tbody>
}
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        var rows_array = [];
        $('#SearchTableBody tr').each(function (i) {
            rows_array[i] = $(this);
        });
        var cpkid = 0;
        var opkid = 0;
        if (rows_array != undefined || rows_array != null) {
            var rowslen = rows_array.length;
            for (var i = -1, n = rowslen; ++i < n;) {
                var row = rows_array[i];
                cpkid = $(row).data('id').pkid;
                if (cpkid != opkid) {
                    // set table row class to .master
                }
                else {
                    // set table row class to .detail
                }
                opkid = cpkid;
            };
        };
    });
    $('.detail').hide();
    $("#SearchTableBody tr.master").click(function () {
        $(this).next("tr").toggle();
        $(this).find('span').text(function (_, value) {
            return value == '-' ? '+' : '-'
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Well, you should provide example of rendered HTML (what browser "sees"), not server-side code. Without HTML it's hard to say anything. But probably `data-id` is String (what it is supposed to be), and you are trying to treat it like some Object.

Answer (score 0):

may be you can try this

```
row.addClass("master");
row.addClass("detail");
```

Hope this be of some help
Happy Learning :)

Comment: It depends on what is really required: _add class_ or _set class_. Maybe lv2rftak will be kind enough to enlighten us.

Comment: I do not use a class attribute when the table is rendered.  I do include a data attribute however.  So, either should be okay.

Comment: To be clearer, the suggestion did not add a class to any rows in the table.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so here's what I finally discovered.  I needed to "seed" the table row with a class.  In this case I simply used class="t".  It does what I need it to do, which is hide the rows with a duplicate primary key.  The data is from a Lucene index that's created using a SQL View with multiple left outer joins.  So, redundant data is unavoidable, but now it's hidden under the first row in the group.

Here's the code in the view:

```
{ ...............
<tbody id="SearchTableBody">
  @foreach (var item in Model.DemographicsAllList)
  {
    <tr class="t" data-id={"pkid":"@item.PK_DemographicsID"}>.....</tr>
  }
</tbody>
}


    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            var rows_array = [];
            $('#SearchTableBody tr').each(function (i) {
                rows_array[i] = $(this);

            });
            var cpkid = 0;
            var opkid = 0;
            if (rows_array != undefined || rows_array != null) {
                var rowslen = rows_array.length;
                for (var i = -1, n = rowslen; ++i < n;) {
                    var row = rows_array[i];
                    cpkid = $(row).data('id').pkid;
                    if (cpkid != opkid) {
                        row.removeClass('t');
                        row.addClass('master');
                        var pkCount = count(rows_array, cpkid);
                        if (pkCount > 1) {
                            row.find('span').text(function (_, value) {
                                return value == '+' ? '+' : '-'
                            });
                        }
                        else {
                            row.find('span').text(function (_, value) {
                                return value == '+' ? '-' : '+'
                            });
                        };
                    }
                    else {
                        row.removeClass('t');
                        row.addClass('detail').find('span').text(function (_, value) {
                            return value == '-' ? '+' : '-'
                        });
                    }
                    opkid = cpkid;
                    //alert(cpkid + ' | ' + opkid);
                };
            };
            function count(array, value) {
                var counter = 0;
                for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
                    if (array[i].data('id').pkid === value) counter++;
                }
                return counter;
            };

            $('.detail').hide();
            $('#SearchTableBody tr.master').click(function () {
                $(this).nextUntil('tr.master').toggle();
            });
        });
</script>
```